# Javascript: removing a fluctuating value from a string

Tags: javascript, str-replace

My Situation:

From the below value, I need to remove `__SCROLLPOSITIONY:1167` part.

```
userValue = "-__LASTFOCUS:-__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR:59AF6414-__SCROLLPOSITIONX:0-__SCROLLPOSITIONY:1167-ctl00$MainContent$appFormDynamic..."
```

The problem is that the value '1167' is changed every time. By using the below code, I can remove only the word but not it's value as it's always changed.

```
userValue = userValue.replace("__SCROLLPOSITIONY:", "");
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Use regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regular expression you can do this

```
userValue = userValue.replace(/__SCROLLPOSITIONY:[^-]+/g, "");
```

This matches to string starting *SCROLLPOSITIONY:* and continues until it finds anything else than hyphen (*-*).

Comment: You Sir/Madam are genius! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: This answer does not work. It was supposed to remove `__` and all the digits after `SCROLLPOSITIONY:`. After running your solution the result is `"-__LASTFOCUS:-__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR:59AF6414-__SCROLLPOSITIONX:0-__167-ctl00$MainContent$appFormDynamic..."` instead of `"-__LASTFOCUS:-__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR:59AF6414-__SCROLLPOSITIONX:0--ctl00$MainContent$appFormDynamic..."`

Comment: Notice `__167` in the first one, that shouldn't be there acc. to the question.